# eclipse Neon Web project with Tomcat8; cannot start server on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, tomcat

I am not able to start the Tomcat8 server in my eclipse (Neon) Dynamic Web project on ubuntu 16.04.
I have seen many postings for similar issues. Most of the answers boil down to;

- creating a symbolic link to /usr/share/tomcat8/conf (linked to
  /etc/tomcat8)
- copying all the files from /etc/tomcat8 to
  *workspace*/Servers/Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost-config

I have tried these and other combinations, but always get this error:

> Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at /Servers/Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost-config. The configuration may be corrupt or incomplete.
>   The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

I believe the conf is good because I can run Tomcat outside of eclipse with no problems...

[image: My Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost-config dir looks like this]

Is there something else I can try?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the error was caused by these lines (below) that I had added when first installing tomcat8.
This did not cause a problem outside of eclipse, but when I commented the lines out, the server started in eclipse.

```
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<user username="paul" password="xxxxx" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/>
```